# Proper way to do "conditional segue" in iOS5

Tags: xcode4, ios5, segue

I'm trying to write really simple iOS5 app just searching for specific type of data.

It contains two screens, the user puts some data in the first, the app checks the data and if it is valid, the app will do a search and show result on new screen.

I'm completely new to iOS and storyboards, I read quite a few tutorials, but haven't been able to figure out how to do the checking of input and switching to new screen properly.

With iOS5 I guess I should use segue but that's all automatic. Even though I can put some code in *prepareForSegue* method, I couldn't find a way how to stop the segue from happening if the check fails, or am I trying to do it completely wrong?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can create "generic" segue by ctrl dragging from the viewController icon at the bottom to the destination. This segue won't be associated with any action. Then in your code where ever the event is using your conditional code that you want to trigger the segue call:

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, the bit that I had been missing was that you ctrl + drag from the `UIViewController` or subclass you are interested in and not the actual control. This definitely beats sub classing the segue itself.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I was also wondering if this is the proper approach? Thanks

Comment: It seems it is not possible to achieve this with a popover segue, it breaks with a Illegal Configuration error: `Popover segue with no anchor` unfortunately :(

Comment: @eric: Thank you thank you so much. your answer saved me and guided me the perfect way....happy coding