# How do I segue to 2 views based on a Segmented Control and an Add button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control in the header of a navigation controller, I want to add an object to a table view controller thats also in this navigation controller.

Heres where my question comes in:

How do I segue from one [+] UIButton to 1 of 2 views, a different add view for each segmented control option. You can only hook up one segue from a UIBarButtonItem in the storyboard, but I wasn't sure If i just hook one up and then change the code somewhere or if i have to build separate xib files (which I'm not familiar with, I'm new to iPhone dev) or how this would work!

Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You make what I call "generic" segues that are not associated with an action/trigger. See my answer here: [How to make and use generic segue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8618471/366010)

Make 2 of these segues, then in your IBAction method for your segmentedControl call `performSegueWithIdentifier:`. For example:

```
- (IBAction)segmentCtrlChanged:(id)sender {
 UISegmentedControl *seg = sender;
 if (seg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) 
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
 else if (seg.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) 
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the view based on the segmented control, I mean I do but thats not my problem.. I want to add 1 of 2 different objects based on the segmented control... so I have 1 UIBarButtonItem  and when its pressed I want to either bring up a "Add Option 1" view or "Add Option 2" view.... but you can only hook up 1 segue to 1 UIBarButtonItem, so i wasn't sure how to bring up the correct view when pressed...

Comment: Sound like you want to display and action sheet. You can then program the buttons in the action sheet to perform the seque as described above.

Comment: well, what about in the storyboard then.. how do I connect 2 views to 1 UIButton in order to have 2 segues?

Comment: If you goto the link in the answer it explains how to make as many segues as you want that can used for whatever purpose. Like using 2 segues for one button.

Comment: Yeah thank you, I was actually trying to hook 2 segues up to the UIBarButtonItem which doesnt work, I needed to go from the controller to the destination views, and then use an IBAction to check the UISegmentedControl and then choose which segue to perform, like the code example you showed, so I got it to work! Thank you!

Comment: Glad you put it all together.

Comment: There's an issue with this approach (IMHO). A Navigation Controller won't create a new controller instace when you tap a tab, but with performSegueWith identifier you do. This might not be an issue, but both are not equivalent (as this thread seems to show).

Answer (score 1):

You only need one segue in your storyboard.
in you viewcontroller, add the

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

method, and use `switch` to decide which segment is being selected.

e.g.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    switch (self.segmentedButton.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
          case 0:
          {
                UIView1 *view1 = (UIView1 *)segue.destinationViewController;
                // do other customization if needed
                break;
          }
          case 1:
          {
                UIView2 *view2 = (UIView2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
                // do other customization if needed
                break;
          }
          default:
               break;
    }
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIStoryboardSegue

Comment: so this will show UIView1 or UIView2 depending on which segmented control option is selected? Or is this just getting you the current view that is or should be on the screen? The views don't need to be pushed onto the window or anything?

Comment: you mean, you are not pushing any view, right? So, you want the [+] button to add either -- for intance -- a UIImage or a UITextfield? What exactly do you want to add to your view?