# Switching storyboard scene from a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

Is is possible to use storyboards to describe a screen where a UISegmentedControl switches in different child scenes for each of its segment?

Say for example you want to have a different perspective on the same data that can be selected from the UISegmentedControl. For example a spreadsheet-like view vs one or more chart views?

(this is on an iPad running iOS 5.x)

I couldn't see a simple way to achieve that, but maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, create a generic segue for each transition by ctrl dragging from the UIViewController icon at the bottom of the view controller in storyboard (These won't be associated with a specific trigger). Then in an IBAction for your segmented control call performSegueWithIdentifier: based on the value of your segmented control.

this is duplicate question of [How do I segue to 2 views based on a Segmented Control and an Add button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728968/how-do-i-segue-to-2-views-based-on-a-segmented-control-and-an-add-button/8729947#8729947)

Comment: Sorry for my search-fu failing me, I'm not sure why. So I was right: there is no "simple" way to do it (where "simple" is defined by pure IB-style, no code). Of course, there isn't much code in what you describe. I guess that's good enough. Storyboards are a bit half-baked in iOS 5. Thanks a lot.

Comment: duh, I can't call `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` because `self.storyBoard` is `nil`. And `self.storyBoard` is `nil` because I load my storyboard programmatically. Is there a way to perform a segue from a programmatically loaded storyboard? (this question might deserver its own SO entry). I load the storyboard programmatically for a couple of reasons: 1- its an evolution from an legacy iOS 4 app, and 2- the app is really big, and one big storyboard for the 8 tabs in the tab bar would be far too monolithic. So I decided to have one storyboard per tab.