# Storyboard: How to add segue to UISegmentedControl without writing code?

Tags: ios, storyboard

A storyboard with several UIViewControllers and a UISegmentedCOntrol.

Each item in the UISegmentedCOntrol is showing a different UIViewController.

Is there a way to add segues without writing any code?

Comment: Currently there is no way like this. But rather than opening new VC using code you can trigger segue to open VC using this code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8729947/1679187